# Compare values in the browser to saved values within Apex Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is it possible to read values from the browser in an apex controller?  Is it possible to do it without javascript (curiosity)?

In a trigger I can use trigger.OldMap and the new value.  However, I'm unsure of how to do this in a controller because the dirty value is in the browser.

I am setting values using the controller on load

```
public cleanseAndPrepareController()
    {
        //hard coded for testing
        dateFilter = date.valueof('2016-06-29');
        curUser = id.valueOf('005r0000000IvGn');
        myActs = new List<activity__c>();
        availableDates = new List<selectOption>();                         

    }

    public List<Activity__C> getActs(){
        setVar();

        return myActs;
    }

    //used for when I filter via a picklist
    public void setVar(){
        if (dateFilterControl != null){
            dateFilter = date.valueOf(dateFilterControl);
        }

        string soql = ' select id, Task_Site__c, Location_is_approximate__c, Activity_Date__c, Check_in_time__c,GeoCode__Latitude__s, GeoCode__Longitude__s, workday__r.owner.name, Task_in_the_field__c,  Check_out_time__c, street_Address__c, city__c, zip_code__c, Mobile_Comments__c, Validated__C ' + 
                      ' from Activity__c ' +                
                      ' where workday__r.ownerid =: curUser and Activity_Date__c =: dateFilter limit 3';


        myActs = database.query(soql);    

        system.debug('********' + dateFilterControl + '**********');    
    }
```

Comment: Are you loading values using the controller?

Comment: yes, I updated to show my constructor and filter methods.

Comment: You're capturing the values when you load, so you need to capture them when they change, so you will have a `dateFilter`, and a `oldDateFilter`, or have ever you want to handle it

Comment: So do I put all potentially changed values as transient getters and setters?  public transient string dateFilterControl {get;set;}.  I'm most interest in Task_Site__c

Comment: How would I do this with a list of values?

Comment: I don't believe you can make these transient, for Lists I would treat it as though they all changed inside that list of any of them changed, I think im misunderstanding of what your trying to do

Comment: So in the constructor I immediately create a duplicate list which is the old values?

Comment: I'm unsure how that still references values in the browser though.

Comment: You would need to {get;set;} the values you loaded on the initial load and then compare them when you save or decide or whatever you want to do with them..  You need to essentially "mock" an `oldMap, oldList`?

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a shot.  So my list after the button is pressed is what is in the browser?

Comment: When you say browser do you mean visualforce?

Comment: yes, in the visualforce page.

Comment: If you'd like to copy or elaborate on my answer, I could mark it as correct to give you the points.  You pointed me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it a pretty dirty (pun intended) way:

get the object.OldValue via SOQL
get the new Value by referencing the datatable constructor list -> converting the datatable list to a map -> using Map.Get to compare object.value = map.get(object.id).value

If I had to worry about heap size (i.e. too many records) there is no way this would work

**VF**

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!Acts}" var="act" id="theTable" styleClass="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer slds-max-medium-table--stacked-horizontal" style="margin-bottom: 30px" rendered="true">

   <apex:column id="button">
       <apex:facet name="header">
           <div class="slds-section-title--divider" >Validate <br></br> Location</div>
        </apex:facet>
   <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-input" value="Validate"  action="{!locationValidate}" reRender="button">
        <apex:param name="selectedRecord" value="{!act.id}" assignTo="{!paramId}"  />
        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" rerender="theTable"/>
    </apex:commandButton>
```

**Apex:**

```
    public List<activity__c> myActs {get; private set;}

    public id paramId {
            get;
            set{
               paramId = value;
            }

        }    

    public List<Activity__C> getActs(){
            setVar();
            return myActs;
        }

        public void setVar(){
            if (dateFilterControl != null){
                dateFilter = date.valueOf(dateFilterControl);
            }

            string soql = ' select id, Task_Site__c, Location_is_approximate__c, Activity_Date__c, Check_in_time__c,GeoCode__Latitude__s, GeoCode__Longitude__s, workday__r.owner.name, Task_in_the_field__c,  Check_out_time__c, street_Address__c, city__c, zip_code__c, Mobile_Comments__c, Validated__C ' + 
                          ' from Activity__c ' +                
                          ' where workday__r.ownerid =: curUser and Activity_Date__c =: dateFilter limit 3';


            myActs = database.query(soql);    
        }

    public PageReference locationValidate()
        {
        //query the database to get "Old Val"
            Activity__c oldVal = [select id, Task_Site__c, Location_is_approximate__c, Activity_Date__c, Check_in_time__c,GeoCode__Latitude__s, GeoCode__Longitude__s, workday__r.owner.name, Task_in_the_field__c,  Check_out_time__c, street_Address__c, city__c, zip_code__c, Mobile_Comments__c, Validated__C 
                                   from Activity__c 
                                   where id =: paramId 
                                   limit 1];
            //create map collection to be able to get object by the Id
            //The object is from the controller which means it's from the UI itself
            map<id, activity__c> curVals = new map<id, activity__c>(myActs);
            //get the object; now I can compare using the Old value (OldVal object) and new value from the Visualforce page (curVal object) which came from constructor list -> map -> search by id -> curVal object
            Activity__c curVal = curVals.get(paramId);      

//using this comparison as an example
if (curVal.Street_Address__c != oldVal.Street_Address__c 
                || curVal.city__c != oldVal.City__c 
                || curVal.zip_Code__c != oldVal.Zip_Code__c)
```